# Curious how others would create a fallback for this: som var = number 0 || false?

Tags: javascript

so, I came across a bug and thought it was interesting. Once I sat and thought about it for 5 seconds, it made sense but curious how one would get past it in the future.

so, I have some hashes set up in an obj.  (snippet of code from a larger obj).

```
   someBigObj : {
       someObj : {
         item1 : 0
         item2:  1
         item4:  2
         item3:  3
      }
  }
```

So, I set it up this way because I need to reference an Array position that corresponds to data that is associated with those items.

So, if I happen to reference item1 -- look what we get.

```
var varReference = someBigObj.someObj['item1'] || false;
// which is equivalent to 
var varReference = 0 || false;
```

see what happens there? that reference is 0. So varReference is always false. I actually want the number 0 in this case because I need to access an array element. I think stringing it is odd to me, because it is not a string, but rather an integer. How can I still use this fallback of || false, but actually get the number 0 to be seen as a valid value.

Note: I understand I can explicitly test etc.. just curious if there is a a shortcut or native js (that I am unaware of) that solves my solutions. figured something like would work but didn't.

```
 Number(0) || false
```

additional note: I ended not putting a || false, as even if it it's not referenced correctly there is no error. So it doesn't actually matter, but I always like to have fallbacks so that is why I am curious.

Comment: Your first code block is not grammatically correct.  You can't use `=` inside a static object declaration.  Did you intend to use `:`?

Comment: I just took a snippet of the code. It's much more involved than what I put. I just wanted to take out the parts that were in question. I see what your point is here. Edited my OP so there is no confusion. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to look at the value in the property (and its falsiness, which fails you sometimes), you should check whether the property exists in the object with the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

```
var varReference = 'item1' in someBigObj.someObj
                     ? someBigObj.someObj['item1']
                     : false;
```

which can be simplified to

```
var varReference = 'item1' in someBigObj.someObj && someBigObj.someObj['item1'];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want falsey values to pass your test, then the test probably needs to look explicitly for `undefined`, not just a falsey value.

```
var varReference = someBigObj.someObj['item1'] !== undefined ? someBigObj.someObj['item1'] : false;
```

Keep in mind that lots of legitimate values are falsey such as `0`, `""`, `null` (and others).

Answer (score 2):

You can use an inline if to check if your value is `undefined` explicity.

```
var varReference = (typeof(someBigObj.someObj['item1']) !== 'undefined') ? someBigObj.someObj['item1'] : false;
```